# Convert from BitmapSource to Visual?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmapsource

Is there any way to convert from a `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource` to a `System.Windows.Media.Visual`? I have an instance of a `BitmapSource` but I'd like to convert it to a `Visual` so I can take advantage of WPF vector graphics. I've seen lots of examples of going from Visual to bitmap but how can I go the other direction using C#?

```
var stream = new FileStream(
    @"C:\Image.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

var decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(
    stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
// Visual visual = bitmapSource.ToVisual(); <-- I'd like to do this
```

Comment: You could put the BitmapSource in an Image control, which is a Visual. However, it would still be a raster image.

Comment: Please be more specific. As Clemens notes, the `Image` control _is_ a `Visual`. Alternatively, you could create a `DrawingVisual` and render the bitmap into that. But either way, you're still going to have a bitmap underneath. What is it about either of those two approaches that doesn't work in your case?

Comment: I'm really looking for a way to have a vector based image underneath. How can I convert a raster image to a vector image?

Comment: @Robin: that's a completely different question. The short answer given the precise wording of the question is, you can't. WPF doesn't have a "bitmap-to-vector" feature. You'd need to write your own or use some third-party library. A web search will show you plenty of options for either.